# Pandas ranking order based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ranking

[image: Click here to see expected result]

Hi Experts,
Please help me to get the expected results, have given below my code
i want ranking priority bucket then look for count.

```
Priority["Rank"] = Priority[["Bucket","Count"]].apply(tuple,axis=1)\
             .rank(method='dense',ascending=False).astype(int)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first put data as text (as DataFrame) so we could simply copy to use in solutions

Comment: your code gives me expected result. I can get something similar to your current result if  I change columns order `["Bucket","Count"]` to `["Count","Bucket"]`. Maybe you use wrong data.

Comment: thank you Furas. Next time whenever i request new query i would update as date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code gives me expected result.

I can get something similar to your current result if I change columns order `["Bucket","Count"]` to `["Count","Bucket"]` - so maybe you use wrong data.

---

Minimal working code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'B': [5,5,4,4,3,2,2,1], 
    'C': [60,3,10,2,35,2,2,3],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['CB'] = df[['C', 'B']].apply(tuple, axis=1).rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
df['BC'] = df[['B', 'C']].apply(tuple, axis=1).rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   B   C  CB  BC
0  5  60   1   1
1  5   3   4   2
2  4  10   3   3
3  4   2   6   4
4  3  35   2   5
5  2   2   7   6
6  2   2   7   6
7  1   3   5   7
```

Comment: Thanks for you for the help